# Training and Testing in neural networks

Tags: matlab, testing, vector, neural-network, training-data

I am having a signal in form of **vector (1*25000)**. I want to split this signal into four parts **x_train, y_train, x_test and y_test** (according to 70-30% training and testing method) in **MATLAB**. Can anyone help me how to split this vector form signal into these four parts?

Answer (score 0):

You can split your vector using [reshape](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) into a matrix with four columns. After that you just assign each column to your respective variable

```
colnr = 4;
rownr = 25000/4;

mat = reshape(vector, [rownr, colnr]);

x_train = mat(:,1);
y_train = mat(:,2);
x_test = mat(:,3);
y_test = mat(:,4);
```